# Combining quadratic and linear matrix terms into a quadratic term

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms

Given

$$ C = AFA^T + A\bar{F} $$

where $A = [A_1 A_2]$, $F = \begin{bmatrix}
F_1 & F_2 \\ 
F_2^T & F_3 
\end{bmatrix}$, $\bar{F} = 2 \begin{bmatrix}
\bar{F}_1 \\ 
\bar{F}_2
\end{bmatrix}$ such that $A_i \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}, F_i = F_i^T \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times k}, \bar{F}_i \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times n}$ and further $F_i, C = C^T  \succeq 0$ with $k \leq n$.

Is it possible to represent $C \succeq 0$ in the following compact-quadratic form:

$$ C = A_M F_M A_M^T $$

for some $A_M$ with $F_M = F_M^T \succeq 0$?

Comment: It is not recommended to simply ask the problem statement, rather include your attempt.

Comment: hi - thank you, i did try manipulating, but, couldn't get too far with this :( not sure if a bigger block-diagonal form for $F_M$ might have been helpful here ... thank you and would appreciate any feedback on this

Comment: the closest i came across was a DT Lyapunov eqn here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation but of course I have an $\bar{F}$ sitting in the second term so am not sure ... i just needed a way to combine the second piece into the first one so was thinking if the second-linear term could be re-written as a quadratic in $A$ somehow via sq. root etc but couldn't arrive at a firm concl. thank you

Comment: Are the $A$'s supposed to be variables and the $F$'s constants, or what?

Comment: @RobertIsrael apologies for the ambiguity, they are matrices .... updated above